# Retrieving the installation path from the installer

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, installation, setup-deployment

I have  a Visual Studio 2008 setup which I created for a Visual C++ project. Is there any way that I can get the installation path that the user specifies at the installation folder prompt?

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Managed to find the answer. There is a property called TARGETDIR in VS setup and deployment, can use that to retrieve the the installation path the user specifies. Just have to use it within square brackets.

Follow the link for more info:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372064(v=VS.85).aspx